# Can a PWA have access to the NFC chip

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, nfc, hybrid-mobile-app

I just start a new project and client wants to use Vue.js to develop a mobile application.

I need to make the choice between an Ionic Vue application and PWA with Vue.js.

I need to have access to the phone's nfc chip and camera.

I prefeer build a PWA application but i don't know if i can access the NFC chip in a PWA application with Vue.js

Comment: Only on Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [Web NFC](https://web.dev/nfc/) in Chrome on Android, but if you need your web app to work across browsers (such as Safari on iOS) then you might  have to explore an Ionic like platform.